# monitor which data is being accessed in remote session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, logmein

HP Tech support has offered to access my PC (laptop) remotely in order to resolve long-ongoing issues with my printer drivers. I have some sensitive data on my PC and want to make sure it is not being accessed:

Will I see all activities being done on my PC directly on my screen, or is there some chance of background connections/processes going on during the remote session?

Is there another way of monitoring what is going on?

Of what I know they will be using a one-session version of 'Log me in'.

(I know that best would be to make all sensitive data inaccessible by transferring or encrypting it - it's just a question of how much time I need to invest for such operation, so I would like to avoid that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see everything that they do on your screen so transferring files elsewhere from your device to something like Dropbox will be visible to you.

In terms of the tool, LogMeIn (Pro version) has file transfer built-in. However you have to share the files with the other side. If you have any concerns, just make sure you don't share/allow that option. Details:

[LogMeIn File sharing](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/webhelp/EN/Pro/LogMeIn/t_sharing_share1.html)